# Adding prev&next buttons only on specific pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 6 pages which are under specific parent page, like:

```
http://example.com/parent/page1
...
http://example.com/parent/page6
```

I want to show previous and next link only on those 6 pages. The problem is that it's showed on all other pages also.

What I'm trying according to documentation I need to use `TRUE` in the links. This is what I have tried in my `function.php`

```
function new_post_navigation(){
?>
    <div class="arrowNav">
        <div class="arrowLeft">
            <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', TRUE); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="arrowRight">
            <?php next_post_link('%link', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>', TRUE); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'new_post_navigation');
```

When I add `TRUE` to the link it's not showed on the page at all. When I put it `FALSE` the links are visible but also all other pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this code and check once, do put the name of the pages inside the array

```
function new_post_navigation(){
$pages = ['page1',.......];
$title = wp_title('',false);
if(in_array($title, $pages)){
?>
    <div class="arrowNav">
        <div class="arrowLeft">
            <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', TRUE); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="arrowRight">
            <?php next_post_link('%link', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>', TRUE); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'new_post_navigation');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should I put in the array - pages ID's?

Comment: Thanks but nothing showed on page even if I change `TRUE` to `FALSE`

Comment: keep it true? and can you give me one url where you want to show the links?

Comment: is your page title this 'digitalna-reklama'??

Comment: Now text is visible but is the text .. title of the page

Comment: what text are you getting and where?

Comment: I'm getting the title of the current page instead of links . At the bottom of the page below copyright text.

Comment: there must be some problem with the title that you are passing in the array, pass the exact slug that you see in the url

Comment: It is exactly the same. For example my pages currently are: `$pages = ['sotsialni-mrezhi','facebook-reklama'];`

Comment: I've found many tutorials and examples how to exclude certain categories from the links but not how to include only certain pages within same category only

Comment: Too bad I didn't saw this earlier but [I found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345562/1158599)

Comment: Anyway, I'm accepting your answer because is helped me to understand this at all.